# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: DefaultPlexusContainer

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin-testing-harness

I wanted to use `maven-plugin-testing-harness` and I am including the following dependency into my project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Running YourMojoTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 sec <<< FAILURE!
testMojoGoal(YourMojoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.017 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/plexus/ContainerConfiguration;[Lcom/google/inject/Module;)V
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setupContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.getContainer(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:152)
    at YourMojoTest.setUp(YourMojoTest.java:13)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

**How do we fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the `org.eclipse.sisu` plexus dependency before the testing-harness causes the correct `DefaultPlexusContainer` class to be loaded by the class loader.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.sisu.plexus</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This seems to work. The order of the dependencies is important.